# Is it possible to skin Qt 4.5 such that it has a 'game-like' interface?

Tags: gui

Is it possible to skin Qt 4.5 such that it looks less like an application framework but more of a game? I guess this probably means replacing the canvas, the title-bar and the artwork of the various widgets. Will such an approach be platform independent too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, and such an approach will be platform independent.

See [Qt reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/stylesheet.html) and [this tutorial](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2009/09/10/qt-stylesheets-tutorial/) for a quick run-down on how to do it.